# java(fx) основы

Tags: java

Изучаю java. Хочу вызвать в консоль текст, который написан в textField. что не так?

Controller:

```
public class Controller {

public static TextField nameRom;

public void prepareROM(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    GlobalClass.prepareRomMethod();
}

public void buildRom(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("Build Rom");
}


public static String nameRom() {
    return nameRom.getText();
}
}
```

GlobalClass:

```
public class GlobalClass {


    public static void prepareRomMethod() {
        System.out.println(Controller.nameRom());
    }

}
```

Ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vngreez.genus.Controller.nameRom(Controller.java:21)
    at com.vngreez.genus.GlobalClass.prepareRomMethod(GlobalClass.java:9)
    at com.vngreez.genus.Controller.prepareROM(Controller.java:12)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: nameRom у вас равен null

Comment: @Виктор я пытаюсь сделать чтобы nameRom получил текст из текстового поля (textField fx:id="nameRom") после нажатия на кнопку (prepareRom событие)

Comment: Изучите что такое Label и как правильно вытягивать данные из View формы в другие классы